# Best way to get InnerXml of an XElement?

Tags: .net, xml, xelement, innerxml

What's the best way to get the contents of the mixed `body` element in the code below?  The element might contain either XHTML or text, but I just want its contents in string form.  The `XmlElement` type has the `InnerXml` property which is exactly what I'm after.

The code as written *almost* does what I want, but includes the surrounding `<body>`...`</body>` element, which I don't want.

```js
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(s));
var templates = from t in doc.Descendants("template")
                where t.Attribute("name").Value == templateName
                select new
                {
                   Subject = t.Element("subject").Value,
                   Body = t.Element("body").ToString()
                };
```

Answer (score 213, accepted):

I wanted to see which of these suggested solutions performed best, so I ran some comparative tests. Out of interest, I also compared the LINQ methods to the plain old **System.Xml** method suggested by Greg. The variation was interesting and not what I expected, with the slowest methods being **more than 3 times slower than the fastest**.

The results ordered by fastest to slowest:

1. CreateReader - Instance Hunter (0.113 seconds)
2. Plain old System.Xml - Greg Hurlman (0.134 seconds)
3. Aggregate with string concatenation - Mike Powell (0.324 seconds)
4. StringBuilder - Vin (0.333 seconds)
5. String.Join on array - Terry (0.360 seconds)
6. String.Concat on array - Marcin Kosieradzki (0.364)

---

**Method**

I used a single XML document with 20 identical nodes (called 'hint'):

```
<hint>
  <strong>Thinking of using a fake address?</strong>
  <br />
  Please don't. If we can't verify your address we might just
  have to reject your application.
</hint>
```

The numbers shown as seconds above are the result of extracting the "inner XML" of the 20 nodes, 1000 times in a row, and taking the average (mean) of 5 runs. I didn't include the time it took to load and parse the XML into an `XmlDocument` (for the **System.Xml** method) or `XDocument` (for all the others).

The LINQ algorithms I used were: *(C# - all take an `XElement` "parent" and return the inner XML string)*

**CreateReader:**

```js
var reader = parent.CreateReader();
reader.MoveToContent();

return reader.ReadInnerXml();
```

**Aggregate with string concatenation:**

```js
return parent.Nodes().Aggregate("", (b, node) => b += node.ToString());
```

**StringBuilder:**

```js
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var node in parent.Nodes()) {
    sb.Append(node.ToString());
}

return sb.ToString();
```

**String.Join on array:**

```js
return String.Join("", parent.Nodes().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

**String.Concat on array:**

```js
return String.Concat(parent.Nodes().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

I haven't shown the "Plain old System.Xml" algorithm here as it's just calling .InnerXml on nodes.

---

**Conclusion**

If performance is important (e.g. lots of XML, parsed frequently), I'd **use Daniel's `CreateReader` method every time**. If you're just doing a few queries, you might want to use Mike's more concise Aggregate method.

If you're using XML on large elements with lots of nodes (maybe 100's), you'd probably start to see the benefit of using `StringBuilder` over the Aggregate method, but not over `CreateReader`. I don't think the `Join` and `Concat` methods would ever be more efficient in these conditions because of the penalty of converting a large list to a large array (even obvious here with smaller lists).

Comment: StringBuilder version can be written on one line: var result = parent.Elements().Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, xelem) => sb.AppendLine(xelem.ToString()), sb => sb.ToString())

Comment: You missed `parent.CreateNavigator().InnerXml` (need `using System.Xml.XPath` for the extension method).

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you need the `.ToArray()` inside `.Concat`, but it seems to make it faster

Comment: In case you don't scroll to the bottom of these answers: consider just stripping the container/root from `.ToString()` per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21642095/1037948).  Seems even faster...

Comment: You should really wrap that `var reader = parent.CreateReader();` in a using statement.

Comment: Seconding @Richard 's comment.  parent.CreateNavigator().InnerXml is particularly nice for projecting as it's inline.

Answer (score 72):

I think this is a much better method (in VB, shouldn't be hard to translate):

Given an XElement x:

```
Dim xReader = x.CreateReader
xReader.MoveToContent
xReader.ReadInnerXml
```

Comment: Nice! This is a lot faster than some of the other methods proposed (I tested them all - see my answer for details). Although all of them do the job, this one does it the fastest - even seens faster than System.Xml.Node.InnerXml itself!

Comment: XmlReader is disposable, so don't forget to wrap it with using, please (I'd edit the answer myself if I knew VB).

Answer (score 22):

How about using this "extension" method on XElement? worked for me !

```
public static string InnerXml(this XElement element)
{
    StringBuilder innerXml = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (XNode node in element.Nodes())
    {
        // append node's xml string to innerXml
        innerXml.Append(node.ToString());
    }

    return innerXml.ToString();
}
```

OR use a little bit of Linq

```
public static string InnerXml(this XElement element)
{
    StringBuilder innerXml = new StringBuilder();
    doc.Nodes().ToList().ForEach( node => innerXml.Append(node.ToString()));

    return innerXml.ToString();
}
```

**Note**: The code above has to use `element.Nodes()` as opposed to `element.Elements()`. Very important thing to remember the difference between the two. `element.Nodes()` gives you everything like `XText`, `XAttribute` etc, but `XElement` only an Element.

Answer (score 17):

With all due credit to those who discovered and proved the best approach (thanks!), here it is wrapped up in an extension method:

```
public static string InnerXml(this XNode node) {
    using (var reader = node.CreateReader()) {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        return reader.ReadInnerXml();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Keep it simple and efficient:

```
String.Concat(node.Nodes().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
```

- Aggregate is memory and performance inefficient when concatenating strings
- Using Join("", sth) is using two times bigger string array than Concat... And looks quite strange in code.
- Using += looks very odd, but apparently is not much worse than using '+' - probably would be optimized to the same code, becase assignment result is unused and might be safely removed by compiler.
- StringBuilder is so imperative - and everybody knows that unnecessary "state" sucks.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up using this:

```
Body = t.Element("body").Nodes().Aggregate("", (b, node) => b += node.ToString());
```

Comment: That will do a lot of string concatenation - I'd prefer Vin's use of StringBuilder myself. The manual foreach is not a negative.

Comment: This method really saved me today, trying to write out an XElement with the new constructor and none of the other methods were lending themselves to it handily, while this one did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I ended up writing an `InnerXml` extension method using the Aggregate method:

```
public static string InnerXml(this XElement thiz)
{
   return thiz.Nodes().Aggregate( string.Empty, ( element, node ) => element += node.ToString() );
}
```

My client code is then just as terse as it would be with the old System.Xml namespace:

```
var innerXml = myXElement.InnerXml();
```

Answer (score 2):

@Greg: It appears you've edited your answer to be a completely different answer.  To which my answer is yes, I could do this using System.Xml but was hoping to get my feet wet with LINQ to XML.

I'll leave my original reply below in case anyone else wonders why I can't just use the XElement's .Value property to get what I need:

@Greg: The Value property concatenates all the text contents of any child nodes.  So if the body element contains only text it works, but if it contains XHTML I get all the text concatenated together but none of the tags.

Comment: I ran into this exact same issue and thought it was a bug:  I had 'mixed' content (i.e. `<root>random text <sub1>child</sub1> <sub2>child</sub2></root>`) which became `random text childchild` via `XElement.Parse(...).Value`

Answer (score 1):

// using Regex might be faster to simply trim the begin and end element tag

```
var content = element.ToString();
var matchBegin = Regex.Match(content, @"<.+?>");
content = content.Substring(matchBegin.Index + matchBegin.Length);          
var matchEnd = Regex.Match(content, @"</.+?>", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
content = content.Substring(0, matchEnd.Index);
```

Comment: neat.  even faster to just use `IndexOf`: `var xml = root.ToString();
 var begin = xml.IndexOf('>')+1;
 var end = xml.LastIndexOf('<');
 return xml.Substring(begin, end-begin);`

Answer (score 1):

doc.ToString() or doc.ToString(SaveOptions) does the work.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, it does not. It also includes the element with all its attributes. Only the content between the start and the end tag is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use the System.Xml namespace objects to get the job done here instead of using LINQ?  As you already mentioned, XmlNode.InnerXml is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if (notice I got rid of the b+= and just have b+)

```
t.Element( "body" ).Nodes()
 .Aggregate( "", ( b, node ) => b + node.ToString() );
```

might be slightly less efficient than

```
string.Join( "", t.Element.Nodes()
                  .Select( n => n.ToString() ).ToArray() );
```

Not 100% sure...but glancing at Aggregate() and string.Join() in Reflector...I *think* I read it as Aggregate just appending a returning value, so essentially you get:

string = string + string

versus string.Join, it has some mention in there of FastStringAllocation or something, which makes me thing the folks at Microsoft might have put some extra performance boost in there.  Of course my .ToArray() call my negate that, but I just wanted to offer up another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var innerXmlAsText= XElement.Parse(xmlContent)
                    .Descendants()
                    .Where(n => n.Name.LocalName == "template")
                    .Elements()
                    .Single()
                    .ToString();
```

Will do the job for you

Answer (score -2):

```
public static string InnerXml(this XElement xElement)
{
    //remove start tag
    string innerXml = xElement.ToString().Trim().Replace(string.Format("<{0}>", xElement.Name), "");
    ////remove end tag
    innerXml = innerXml.Trim().Replace(string.Format("</{0}>", xElement.Name), "");
    return innerXml.Trim();
}
```

Comment: And also if the element has any attributes or even only a space too much the logic fails.