# Want to return the entire contents of an XElement as a string

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I'm a newbie to LINQ in C# and am using it to read in and work with XML files.

I'm able to navigate up and down my elements, but what I want for some elements is to return the *entire* contents as a string.  Meaning, I have an element like this:

```
<element1>
    <subel1> some text here </subel1>
</element1>
```

When I get the value of element1, I want to get back the entire contents as a text string like this:  `"<subel1> some text here </subel1>"`

Does that make sense?  Can anyone help?

(closed as duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edit: after replying, I found an exact duplicate, by searching ["XElement InnerXml"](http://www.google.com/search?q=xelement+innerxml))

With `XmlDocument` that would be just `.InnerXml` - not sure about `XElement`, though. Perhaps cheat?

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var el in foo.Nodes()) sb.AppendLine(el.ToString());
    string s = sb.ToString();
```