# Converting the children of XElement to string

Tags: c#, xml, xhtml, innerhtml, xelement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to get InnerXml of an XElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement)

I am using an XElement to hold a block of HTML serverside.

I would like to convert the children of that XElement into a string, sort of like an "InnerHtml" property does in javascript.

Can someone help me on this please? :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The other answers will work if the element only contains other elements.  If you want to include text as well, you'll want to use Nodes() instead of Elements():

```
var result = string.Concat(element.Nodes());
```

Comment: I just tested this one, it worked perfectly. This was my first question on Stack Overflow, I am certainly impressed by how quick I got it answered. :)

Answer (score 3):

The XElement class doesn't provide a method to directly get the "inner XML" of the element.
You can concatenate the child elements manually though, for example using

```
string result = string.Concat(element.Elements());
```

or

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, element.Elements());
```

Answer (score 2):

See a variety of options, with performance testing here: [Best way to get InnerXml of an XElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement)

You may want to create an extension method for your quiver as such:

```
/// <summary>
///  Gets the inner XML of an <see cref="XElement"/>. Copied from
///  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">The element.</param>
/// <returns>The inner XML</returns>
public static string GetInnerXml(this XElement element)
{
    var reader = element.CreateReader();
    reader.MoveToContent();
    return reader.ReadInnerXml();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach(var element in Element.Elements()) {
  yield return element.ToString();
}

Returns an IEnumerable with strings.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like this, thanks to Quartermeister

```
string result = string.Concat(instanceXElement.Nodes().ToArray());
```

I was having just HTML code in my instanceXElement that i wanted to fetch out exactly.