# Converting XElement into XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement, xmlnode

I know there is no direct method of doing it but still..
Can  we convert `XElement` element  into `XmlNode`.
Options like `InnerText` and `InnerXml` are  `XmlNode` specific.

so,if i want to use these options, what can be done to convert  `XElement` into `XmlNode` and  vice versa.

Comment: There are ways to get InnerXml from XElement - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is converting from string to XElement to XmlNode and back to XElement.  ToString() on XElement is similar to OuterXml on XmlNode.

```
    XElement xE = XElement.Parse("<Outer><Inner><Data /></Inner></Outer>");

    XmlDocument xD = new XmlDocument();
    xD.LoadXml(xE.ToString());
    XmlNode xN = xD.FirstChild;

    XElement xE2 = XElement.Parse(xN.OuterXml);
```

Comment: You could also use ImportNode https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 64):

I use the following extension methods, they seem to be quite common:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static XElement ToXElement(this XmlNode node)
    {
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = xDoc.CreateWriter())
            node.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
        return xDoc.Root;
    }

    public static XmlNode ToXmlNode(this XElement element)
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
            return xmlDoc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to make `ToXmlNode` return `xmlDoc.DocumentElement` to get the behavior I expected.  In particular, my `XElement` had annotations, but my `XmlNode` did not.  Otherwise very helpful.

Comment: `return xmlDoc;` should be corrected as `return xmlDoc.FirstChild;`

Answer (score 3):

Based on BrokenGlass's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5399711/113108), if you wish to embed the XmlNode to an XmlDocument, than use:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static XmlNode ToXmlNode(this XElement element, XmlDocument xmlDoc = null)
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            if(xmlDoc==null) xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            return xmlDoc.ReadNode(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: if you try to insert into a document a node, that is created by a different document, than it will throw an exception: "The node to be inserted is from a different document context."

Answer (score 3):

```
XElement xelement = GetXElement();
XmlNode node = new XmlDocument().ReadNode(xelement.CreateReader()) as XmlNode;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the shortest way is following:

```
Dim xn as XmlNode = xdoc.ReadNode(xElem.CreateReader)
```

That's all! Convert to C# is trivial.

Comment: I tried to replicate this, but the xml document is always empty that way

Comment: @Thoker maybe the reason is blank xdoc? Where xdoc it is yours xml document.

Answer (score 0):

The "vice-versa" is very easy in C# unless I'm missing something:

`My_XML_Element = (XmlElement) My_XML_Node;`