# XPathSelectElement("/root/title").ToString() selects also the xml name around

Tags: c#, dom, innerxml

When I do

```
XPathSelectElement("/root/title").ToString()
```

I get for example `<title>this is an <strong>example</strong></title>`. But I don't want to get `<title>` around the text.

When I do

```
XPathSelectElement("/root/title").Value
```

then it gets only the text without `<strong></strong>`

How can I solve this?

Comment: I tagged your question as C#. I am correct, or is this VB.NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to get InnerXml of an XElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement)

Comment: @user: good. See the other question I linked to. It has some very good answers, and I think you can find yours there.

Comment: Not about XPath but DOM method instead. Retagging.

Answer (score 0):

From memory:

```
XPathSelectElement("/root/title/text()").ToString()
```

Alternatively, you might select all child nodes (`/root/title/*`) and join the their string representations

Comment: No. That gets the same as `.Value`.

Comment: I was still typing I guess :)

Comment: the first doesn't work, i get an error but dont know what exactly. and the second: '/root/title/*' gives a nullreferenceexception if there is only plain text in the xml node

Comment: You can, of course, check for nulls. However, I think the real trouble is that you wanted text nodes as well as elements. My xpath is (unfortunately) too sloppy to remember whether that was (standard) possible

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `XmlReader` and read the inner xml from it.

```
XElement element = doc.XPathSelectElement("/root/title");
XmlReader reader = element.CreateReader();
reader.MoveToContent();
string innerXml = reader.ReadInnerXml();
```