# How can I use C# to create XML without a containing element?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am using the following:

```
XElement select = new XElement("select");
XElement optGroup = null;

if (topics.Count() > 0) {
    optGroup = new XElement("optgroup", new XAttribute("label", "Admin"));
    optGroup.Add(new XElement("option", new XAttribute("value", "99"), new XText("Select Topic")));
    optGroup.Add(new XElement("option", new XAttribute("value", "00"), new XText("All Topics")));
    select.Add(optGroup);
    foreach (var topic in topics) {
        // skip root topic
        if (!topic.RowKey.EndsWith("0000")) {
            // optgroup
            if (topic.RowKey.EndsWith("00")) {
                optGroup = new XElement("optgroup", new XAttribute("label", topic.Title));
                select.Add(optGroup);
            }
                // option
            else if (optGroup != null) {
                optGroup.Add(new XElement("option", new XAttribute("value", topic.RowKey), new XText(topic.Title)));
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    optGroup = new XElement("optgroup", new XAttribute("label", "Admin"));
    optGroup.Add(new XElement("option", new XAttribute("value", "88"), new XText("No Topics")));
}                     
return (select.ToString());
```

It processes rows in a variable and uses the data to create a `<select> ...  </select>` element for HTML.

It works however what I need is the contents of the `<select>` and not the opening `<select>` and closing `</select>` elements. Is there some way I could make this just return contents and not the outer `<select>` ?

Comment: I think this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

to get access to the extension methods defined in the [`Extensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299124.aspx) class in that namespace to get an [`XPathNavigator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx) and its [`InnerXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.innerxml.aspx) property:

```
string inner = select.CreateNavigator().InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just trim what you don't want from the result.

```
return (select.ToString().Replace("<select>","").Replace("</select>",""));
```