# Get only the text of a xml node

Tags: .net, xml

I have this xml:

```
    <root>      
      <sub>maintext1
        <subsub>subtext1</subsub>
        <subsub>subtext2</subsub>
      </sub>          
    </root>
```

I initially tried < sub>.Value, but this returned everything inside the sub, then < sub>.ToString which does the same thing. I searched for a solution but everywhere was used the xmlElement.InnerText but I need it for xElement which isn't available. How can I use the inner text property for the xElement?

Comment: @sll and  lazyberezovsky ,  Why is this xml invalid and why can't I have `maintext1 between <sub> node and <subsub> element.`? It seems to be a completely valid xml. I may be wrong. A reference please.

Comment: Agreed, this XML is valid and it parses fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to get InnerXml of an XElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement)

Comment: Apologize for confisuing I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the nodes of an `XElement` of a specific type by using the `OfType` Linq extension on the return value of the `Nodes` method.

```
XElement.Nodes().OfType<XText>()
```

This example gets the value you're looking for, I think:

```
var xml = 
    @"<root>      
       <sub>maintext1
        <subsub>subtext1</subsub>
        <subsub>subtext2</subsub>
       </sub>          
      </root>";
var xel = XElement.Parse(xml);
var textNodes = xel.Element("sub").Nodes().OfType<XText>();
var mainText1 = textNodes.First().Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

`maintext1` creates a text node, so you could do something like this:

```cs
var xml = @"<root>      
<sub>maintext1
<subsub>subtext1</subsub>
<subsub>subtext2</subsub>
</sub>          
</root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var txt = (IEnumerable<object>)doc.XPathEvaluate("/root/sub/text()");
var textNode = (XText)txt.First();
Console.WriteLine(textNode.Value);
```

Note that you will need the following namespaces imported for this to compile:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```