# Building xml from scratch and getting result in string?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to build up xml document from scratch with use linq-to-xml.

```
XElement root = new XElement("RootNode");
            XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""), root
            );
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                XElement element = new XElement("SetGrid");
                element.SetElementValue("ID", j);                    
                root.Add(element);

            }
   var reader = doc.CreateReader();//doc has 10 elements inside root element
   string result = reader.ReadInnerXml();//always empty string
```

How can I get string from `XDocument`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `string result = doc.ToString()` or

```
var wr = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(wr);
string result = wr.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

One option for empty string as per documentation.

`XmlReader` return:

> All the XML content, including markup, in the current node. If the
>   current node has no children, an empty string is returned. If the
>   current node is neither an element nor attribute, an empty string is
>   returned.

try:

```
XmlReader reader = doc.CreateReader();
reader.Read(); 
string result = reader.ReadInnerXml()
```

Comment: This is totaly not the case in question - there're 10 elements inside the root element

Answer (score 0):

```
var wr = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(wr);
var xmlString = wr.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a full answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704579/938883).

Long story short, you're missing `reader.MoveToContent();`

i.e. it should be:

```
var reader = root.CreateReader();
reader.MoveToContent(); // <- the missing line
string result = reader.ReadInnerXml();
```

This way the `result` won't be empty and you even don't have to create `XDocument`

So the full code from the original question + the fix is:

```
XElement root = new XElement("RootNode");
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    XElement element = new XElement("SetGrid");
    element.SetElementValue("ID", j);
    root.Add(element);
}

var reader = root.CreateReader();// root has 10 elements
reader.MoveToContent(); // <-- missing line
string result = reader.ReadOuterXml(); // now it returns non-empty string
```

Output:

```
<RootNode><SetGrid><ID>0</ID></SetGrid><SetGrid><ID>1</ID></SetGrid><SetGrid><ID>2</ID></SetGrid><SetGrid><ID>3</ID></SetGrid><SetGrid><ID>4</ID></SetGrid><SetGrid><ID>5</ID></SetGrid><SetGrid><ID>6</ID></SetGrid><SetGrid><ID>7</ID></SetGrid><SetGrid><ID>8</ID></SetGrid><SetGrid><ID>9</ID></SetGrid></RootNode>
```

Note: The code is tested in Visual Studio 2013 / .NET Framework 4.5

MDSN Reference: [XmlReader.ReadOuterXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readouterxml(v=vs.110).aspx)