# How to retrieve HTML from XElement without parent tag?

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have xml like this

```
XElement xe = "<root>
    <mynode>
        Text with link <a href=''>Test</a>
    </mynode>
</root>";

public static string GetHtmlFromXElement(this XElement xe)
{
    return xe.ToString();
}
```

If I use

```
string result = xe.Element("mynode").GetHtmlFromXElement();
```

I get

```
<mynode>Text with link <a href=''>Test</a></mynode>
```

But I need

```
Text with link <a href=''>Test</a>
```

How to do this right?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Best way to get InnerXml of an XElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3793/299327)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement) looks like roughly the same question, with some pretty in-depth answers.

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer there. var reader = xe.CreateReader();  reader.MoveToContent(); return reader.ReadInnerXml().Trim();

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string result = xe.Element("mynode").Value;
```

Comment: It returns the text only without html.