# Replacing elements in XElement breaks foreach loop

Tags: c#, xml

I have string

```
<div class="TextP">
   <span class="bold" style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span> text 
   <span class="bold" style="font-weight: bold;">italic</span> text 
   <span class="bold" style="font-weight: bold;">underlined</span> text
</div>
```

which I parse to `XElement` object and than I need to replace the formating spans with other elements. So I have written this code

```
//el is the root div
foreach (XElement el in e.Elements())
        {
            switch (el.Name.ToString().ToLower())
            {
                //The method is more complex, but only this part doesnt work, therfore this only case
                case "span":
                    if (el.Attribute("class") != null)
                    {
                        switch (el.Attribute("class").Value)
                        {
                            case "underline" :
                                el.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse("<U>" + el.Value + "</U>"));
                                break;
                            case "bold":
                                el.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse("<B>" + el.Value + "</B>"));
                                break;
                            case "italic":
                                el.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse("<I>" + el.Value + "</I>"));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when I replace the first `span` the foreach loop breaks and the two other `spans` remain unreplaced.
I think It's because the `.Elements()` collection changes, but I can't  figure out, how should I change my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you can't make changes to a collection as you're iterating through it. One way to get around this is to make a copy of your collection and iterate through that:

```
foreach (XElement el in e.Elements().ToArray()) // or ToList
{
    // ...
}
```

This will find all the child elements of `e` at the beginning of the loop and store them in a different collection (using the Linq [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) / [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method). This way, the elements collection can be freely modified inside the loop.

Comment: Personally I prefer `ToList` - I generally prefer lists over arrays, and I *think* in the case of LINQ to Objects, it's slightly more efficient too.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! And one more question, is there any quick elegant way to instead of `el.Value` get `innerXml` because the formating spans can be nested of course and I need to use `e.Descendants()` instead

Comment: @JonSkeet It looks like both use an identical strategy--dynamically sized arrays starting at size 4 and doubling each time--but indeed, `ToList` saves one array copy because the final array is not re-sized back down before you get an enumerator. I learned something new today, thanks :)

Comment: @david See [Best way to get InnerXml of an XElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement)

Comment: @p.s.w.g I think the good alternative for ToList/ToArray is Reverse.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Yes, it's the lack of the final array copy which I was referring to, but didn't want to go into too much detail ;)