# Get the Decendants of a XML doc

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm attempting to get just the inner xml of the following XML/XAML doc.

```
<Root>
    <Child1>
       Hello
    </Child1>

</Root>
```

Desired Result

```
    <Child1>
       Hello
    </Child1>
```

My code below Shows this Message

```
Hello
```

I'm expecting the Child elements as well but unable to achieve this.

**Code**

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xx);
string fragment = (string)doc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Do not cast to `string`, use `ToString()` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to get InnerXml of an XElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement)

Comment: @Dmitry, ah, but the questioner wants the *outer* XML of the element :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Or the *inner* XML of the `Root` node. :)

Comment: Everything inside root.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `ToString()` instead of casting to `string`.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xx);
string fragment = doc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```