# How to acces xml node value if it has '<' in it

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a code like this

```
 var summary = member.Select(o => o.Element("summary"))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

This gives the value like

```
<summary>
   Gets the number of elements contained in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />. 
</summary>
```

When i try to get the value from summary like `summary.value` it gives only the value

> Gets the number of elements contained in the .

The part `<see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1" />` in that string is not coming.

Please help in fixing this.

Captured on debugging.

[image: Capture on debugging for reference]

[image: Summary value]

**UPDATE**

I tried escaping as per comment

```
        var summary = member.Select(o => o.XPathSelectElement("summary").Value.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("&gt;", ">"))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Still same result. May be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You should escape the value beforehand with `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>` and `&amp;` for `&`

Comment: How can i improve this question. Down voters please suggest.

Comment: You could indicate how your xml is being built, and if the xml content is already escaped (you could check if with notepad instead of a xml viewer if the file in question has the malformed xml (eg: `<` in text instead of `&lt;`)

Comment: @shansfk you want to [get 'InnerXml' of the `XElement`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement)

Comment: @har07 Thanks for the link. I did the same in that answer. It worked. Thank u once again. At least i got an answer before the question got closed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement) I created a `XmlReader` object and read the content and get the inner xml. The code is:

```
public static string InnerXml(this XElement self)
{
    var reader = self.CreateReader();
    reader.MoveToContent();

    return reader.ReadInnerXml()?.Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get it like that is because the `XDocument` is recognizing it as an nested element. You should convert that element into plain text and then you'll have it.

Something like:

```
var element = document.Element("summary");
var value = element.Value;

value += string.Join(", ", document.Element("summary")
                                   .Descendants()
                                   .Where(x => x.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element
                                   .Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

Obviously you can not use `.Descendants()` and use `.Element()` or add `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of working with the collection, but this is the general idea

Comment: Thanks for replying back.

Comment: I referred [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/best-way-to-get-innerxml-of-an-xelement) suggested by har07. That worked for me

Comment: Ok cool :) So maybe: if my answer helped you solve it mark it as solved. otherwise if it didn't help you understand the problem then you can also post your answer and mark it solved with your answer

Comment: Yes will do that. Thanks !.